# NodeJS exec throwing ENOMEM when memory is available

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running pdfinfo command to get info about a pdf of size 100KB. The relevant code is

```
    const pdfInfo = execute(`pdfinfo '${input}' | grep Pages`)
      .then(stdout => {
        var pdfLength = 0;
        pdfLength = stdout.match(/Pages:\s+(\d+)/)[1];
        return pdfLength;
    })
    function execute(command) {
      return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
          if (error || stderr) {
            rej(error || stderr);
          } else {
            res(stdout);
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

After processing for few files the memory usage just keeps increasing

```
 PM2 details of the process
 Mem: 431 MB    CPU:  0 %
```

If I see the memory available on the server then that is

```
/home/core-server # free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2000       1341        659         20         21        173
-/+ buffers/cache:       1145        854
Swap:            0          0          0
```

The memory is available and still I get the error

```
2019-01-10T00:46:42.266Z Error: spawn ENOMEM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:358:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:533:9)
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:216:15)
    at exec (child_process.js:147:18)
    at /home/core-server/helper/ppt2svg.js:42:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at execute (/home/core-server/helper/ppt2svg.js:41:10)
    at pdf2svg (/home/core-server/helper/ppt2svg.js:53:18)
    at ppt2svg (/home/core-server/helper/ppt2svg.js:93:12)
    at uploadPresentation.single.err (/home/core-server/api/sessions/index.js:174:25)
```

May anyone please provide me any ideas as why this might be happening?

Edit: BTW, everything else on server is working fine but it is the exec method that is having this problem

Comment: Probably the node process ran out of memory

Comment: @0.sh That is my main concern but how as node takes memory as much as available in the OS. I still have 1GB memory available and pdfinfo for 100kb file is not even going to 1GB if I monitor the memory usage in real time.

Comment: [Here is another possible cause of your problem](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25382). Unfortunately looks like there is no common solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know node.js has a default memory limits. Something like 1G on 32-bit and 1.7G on 64-bit systems. But, fortunately, you can increase it by issue `--max_old_space_size=<size>` option in node.js command line. Value `<size>` in Mb.

Comment: May you please refer to any source where it say this? As far as I remember, it has no limit on 64 bit system

Comment: From [v8 developers blog](https://v8.dev/blog/heap-size-limit) : 
_**V8 has a hard limit on its heap size. This serves as a safeguard against applications with memory leaks.**_